# How to provide options when writing to S3 from R using s3write_using?

Tags: r, amazon-s3

Writing to an S3 bucket from R using the `aws.s3` library works like so

```
s3write_using(iris, FUN = write.csv, object = "iris.csv", bucket = "some-bucket")
```

But I cannot get an option to work. E.g. `row.names=FALSE`

#### What I've tried so far

I have tried the following

```
s3write_using(iris, FUN = write.csv, object = "iris.csv", bucket = "some-bucket", opts = list(row.names=FALSE))

s3write_using(iris, FUN = write.csv, object = "iris.csv", bucket = "some-bucket", opts = list("row.names"=FALSE))

# Seen here: https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/issues/200
s3write_using(iris, FUN = write.csv, object = "iris.csv", bucket = "some-bucket", opts=list(headers = c('row.names' = 'FALSE')))
```

None of the above errors (or even warns), but the resulting `.csv` has row names, which it shouldn't

#### Question

How do I write to an S3 bucket from R using `s3write_using` and specify `row.names = FALSE` (or any other optional parameter)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manual for `s3write_using` says:

> Optional additional arguments passed to put_object or save_object, respectively.

So the optional parameters are passed to other aws.s3 functions and not `write.csv`.

But you can always define your own function:

```
mywrite <- function(x, file) {
     write.csv(x, file, row.names=FALSE)
}
```

And then use this function in lieu of write.csv:

```
s3write_using(iris, FUN = mywrite, object = "iris.csv", bucket = "some-bucket")
```

You can even make a function generator, that is a function which returns a function which wraps around `write.csv` to provide the necessary arguments:

```
customize.write.csv <- function(row.names=TRUE, ...) {
    function(x, file) {
        write.csv(x, file, row.names=row.names, ...)
    }
 }
```

Which you can use like this:

```
s3write_using(iris, 
    FUN = customize.write.csv(row.names=FALSE, dec=","), 
    object = "iris.csv", 
    bucket = "some-bucket")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you can just add the options you want at the end, give it a try:

```
s3write_using(iris, 
    FUN = write.csv, 
    object = "iris.csv", 
    bucket = "some-bucket",
    row.names=FALSE, dec=","
)
```